# Reverse for 'ques_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ques_detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error:

> Reverse for 'ques_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ques_detail/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Does anyone know how to solve it?

I tried solutions posted on many sites but nothing worked. Someone kindly help.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('logout', views.logout, name='test_logout'),
    path('register', views.register, name = 'register'),
    path('', views.welcome, name='welcome'),
    path('instructions', views.instructions, name = 'instructions'),
    path('ques_detail/<int:pk>/',views.ques_detail,name='ques_detail')
]
```

**views.py**

```
def instructions(request):
    return render(request,'events/instructions.html')

def ques_detail(request, pk):
    ques = get_object_or_404(Questionm, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'events/ques_detail.html', {'ques': ques})
```

**instructions.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div  class="register">
     <h1>Instructions</h1>
    </div>
    <br><br><hr><hr>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="start">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 350px; 
height: 80px;font-size : 500px;"><a href="{% url 'ques_detail' pk=ques.pk %}"> 
<h4>Start Test</h4></a></button>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you check the value of `ques.pk` in the template instructions.html ? For this line : `{% url 'ques_detail' pk=ques.pk %}`. For example, an empty string could throw this error

Comment: Can you please tell how to check it !?

Comment: you can add `{{ ques.pk }}`  just after `<div class="start">` (or somewhere else) to display the value. And you can also analyze the view calling this template to understand how  `ques` is declared

Comment: @PRMoureu How can I convert pk from empty string to an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is missing in the view `instructions` to call the *Start Test* page properly.

In the template you define the button with an url to call a question :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 350px; 
    height: 80px;font-size : 500px;">
    <a href="{% url 'ques_detail' pk=ques.pk %}"> 
    <h4>Start Test</h4></a>
</button>
```

`{% url 'ques_detail' pk=ques.pk %}` will call the view `ques_detail` and try to pass the question ID with the parameter `pk`, OK, but you never define `ques.pk` here, that's why you got an empty string and the reverse error.

When **instructions.html** is rendered, you have to define a `ques` object in the context of the template, like you do with `render(request, 'events/ques_detail.html', {'ques': ques})`.

So you could have a view like the following :

```
def instructions(request):
    ques = Questionm.objects.first()
    context = {'ques': ques}
    return render(request,'events/instructions.html', context)
```

(I query a question randomly (`Questionm.objects.first()`) you will have to replace this to query the question you need.)